# Turned off 2 factor auth in Google but still had to verify on phone

Tags: gmail

I turned off 2 factor auth in my Google account, but today I had to verify on my phone when logging in. After logging in, I double checked and, indeed, 2 factor auth was turned off.

Why would this happen? Is there like a 3rd level here that I can't turn off or something or is this a bug?

Comment: Google does this sometimes even when 2FA is off.

Comment: Google enable 2-step authentication on all accounts a few months ago. Questions about your Google Account are out of scope here at Super User